# vba in html- Need to onmouseup login which is not a button

Tags: html, vba

Is it possible to automate a login page using vba which has a mousedown and mouseup clicks . When i click a login button it has a mousedown click as it doesn't have any button in order to automate using vba.

Please let me know if its possible to do so in vba using some functions

Please copy the URL and paste in internet tab: "http://discovery.ariba.com/rfx/3796429". After clicking the URL you will enter to Ariba Discovery site and there you have this Ship to Service location field. In that ship to service location field there are multiple locations and we need to click on "Show more". To click show more if we see the html code it's not a button in order to automate the click. It's awmouseup and aw is the page name i guess. I would recommend you yo use google chrome and try inspecting the html code. I need to automate the click using VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ie.document.getElementById("_sbsyf").click
```

should do it

Comment: My code is working till that show more feature . After then not able to automate the show more option. as its onmouseup thing and not a button to perform click option. I tried using the id as you told it is not working. Will you be able to provide me a code to click the show more option after clicking the link: "http://discovery.ariba.com/rfx/3796429". It will helpful to me to embed the code into my code.

Comment: please help me with this.

Comment: I did take a look at that page, and was unable to activate the link.  I have no idea why not.